# How to improve my answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I want to give answers to some questions that I know the answer to, but I don't know how to express my answer. What should I keep in mind when I answer any questions?

Comment: With regard to the specific answer you posted, a comment was provided detailing how your answer did not answer the question which was asked, namely the question was asking for a keyboard skin for the existing keyboard on the laptop, rather than an entirely separate keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two good places to start are

- [Two Minute Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Especially the help center contains a lot of information about how to participate on the site and how the different things work. There is also one page about [How do I write a good answer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).